# Translating "哩哏楞"

Tags: translation

In the TV drama [追捕 第3集](http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMjQ4NDM1ODQ4.html)

梁队 (梁志群队张) and 鲁队 (鲁炼) are in 贺局's office discussing the case, and at 27:54 梁队 says to 鲁队: `甭给我来这个哩哏楞`.

(Dialog especially of the police officers consists mainly of Beijing dialect, which although not in dictionaries  often is explained elsewhere on the Internet, which seems not to be the case with 哩哏楞 although it occurs in the names of many Internet pages.)

Comment: http://qiangyou.org/bbs/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=2600 seems instructive as well: 

哩哏愣 可以翻译成 bla bla bla
意思是 废话，大话，假话，空话，无聊的话

根据不同语境，可以理解为：
书面一些的表达法：
少来这跟我忽悠
少跟我扯没用的
少来着跟我得瑟（装B）
少跟我来这套

Comment: i。o。w。 哩哏愣（lèng）is a variant of 哩哏棱 （léng）

Comment: yeah it's dialect and on top of that onomatopoeia for beijing opera zither. gonna get all sorts of weird character equivalents.;)

Answer (score 4):

It's a kind of dialect, means `blandishments`, `sweet words`.

> 哩格儿楞
>   在人们的对话中，常会听到这样的话：“你少给我来这个‘哩格儿楞’！”意思是你别给我花言巧语、油嘴滑舌。其实这个俗语是近年由北京传来的，也算是准河北方言——现在在河北各地都能听到人说这个词。
>   该词源于京剧票友在清唱时，对唱腔开始前的“板头”和唱腔中间的“过门”曲调，往往以口舌代乐器，唱作“隆格哩格儿楞”，有的“过门”曲调委婉，绕来绕去，所以人们就把“哩格儿楞”来比喻某些人的花言巧语。

Reference: [少整哩格儿楞](http://www.hbqnb.com/news/html/Localism/2007/326/07326319BC2AI1FI8CEGK79G7FK7.html)

Comment: i。a。w。哩格儿楞 is a variant of 哩哏楞

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://fangyan.yjba.net/html/shandong/536.html) it's defined as 装糊涂，办事敷衍. Other places define it as 閒扯 but then it's prefixed with 扯. Based on the limited context above I would go with "Don't play dumb with us" or maybe "Stop bullshitting us".

Answer (score 1):

27:54 梁队 says to 鲁队: 甭给我来这个哩哏楞.

27:54 Captain Liang says to Captain Lu: Don't bullshit me.

27:54 Captain Liang says to Captain Lu: Save that crap.

27:54 Captain Liang says to Captain Lu: Cut to the chase.

All the translation are possible, but the wording really depends on the context and the emotion of and relation between the characters.

哩哏楞 basically is often used to denote off topic talking or behaviour that doesn't make a point or simply the perfunctory. Some times "来(这/这个/这套)哩哏楞" can be replaced by verb 扯淡.

To understand the meaning, you can understand the word as sweeping onomatopoetic for the sound of humming instrumental part of traditional operas, and now used to denote all non-essential or off-topic or perfunctory talking or behaviour that may seem that the speaker was talking but actually they did't say anything.